# Catalogue Price Rules not working properly for different customer groups

Tags: magento2, price, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

I am trying to apply catalogue price rule for a different customer group, It's working fine for "general" customer group but when I changed it to different customer group then the discount is not applied to products.